# Setting selected option in drop-down box

Tags: php, mysql, select

My `SELECT` looks like the following:

```
<?php  
$query = "SELECT * FROM Rec_SW2_Rel AS a JOIN SW2 b ON a.Sbj_ID = b.IDsbj GROUP BY a.Sbj_ID ORDER BY b.Descriptor";
 $result = mysql_query($query);  
?>
<select name="country" onchange="getState(this.value)">
    <?php
     while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
     {
    ?>
<option value="<?php echo $line['Sbj_ID']; ?>"> 
<?php echo $line['Descriptor']; ?> 
</option>
<?php
}
mysql_close();
?>
</select>
```

Querying the DB and setting up the drop-down works. The problem is that the value listed first isn't automatically selected. If a user wants to use it, for further navigation, they must first select a different one and then select the first once again.

I couldn't alter the values in the DB. If I insert `selected='selected'` it returns the last value of the result set, but always without being selected.

Comment: You shouldn't use mysql, instead use mysqli http://uk1.php.net/mysqli or PDO http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: So what do you actually want? An empty row that shows up first, that the user must then select a real value from?

Comment: An empty row could be fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You maybe want this? First selected option when the form is loaded is blank.

```
<select name="country" onchange="getState(this.value)">
<option value=""></option>
<?php
 while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
 {
```

or select the selected data from the database? `selected` column with `selected` value.

```
<select name="country" onchange="getState(this.value)">
<?php
$first = true;
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $line['Sbj_ID']; ?>" <?php echo ($line['selected']=='selected') ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ; ?>>
```

Comment: The first option is perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can test with respect to $line['Sbj_ID'] if this is = to the value you want by default

```
 <?php  
$query = "SELECT * FROM Rec_SW2_Rel AS a JOIN SW2 b ON a.Sbj_ID = b.IDsbj GROUP BY a.Sbj_ID ORDER BY b.Descriptor";
 $result = mysql_query($query);  
?>
<select name="country" onchange="getState(this.value)">
    <?php

     while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
     {
 ?>
<option value="<?php echo $line['Sbj_ID']; ?>" <?php if($line['Sbj_ID']==value_you_want_selected){?>selected<?php } ?>> 
<?php echo $line['Descriptor']; ?> 
</option>
<?php
$i++; }
mysql_close();
?>
```